# In what order to place sort up/down buttons in a table?

Tags: buttons, tables, data-tables, sorting

This is a simple question: **In what order should I place the move down and move up button in a sortable table?**

This may be "opinion based", but I hope it's not and there is a definite preference. Out of the blue, I would do it like on the image below.

Or should I put the move up button first?

[image: sortable table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're sorting items, you want to see the item name/identifier to know that you're putting it in the right location.

Since the name/identifier is typically the 1st piece of info displayed on the left, you want your sort controls close to that.

Therefore **having the controls on the left is preferable**.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqTkmC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Very helpful advice, didn't think about that from my developer's perspective! So you say the move up button should be first, too?

Comment: @bytecode77 Yes. They should be seen as a pair.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a little logic so that the first record only has a working down button, and the last record only has a working up button.

You can either grey out the inactive buttons for the first/last records, or even better hide the inactive buttons, e.g. the first record only has a down button and the last record only has an up button.

Comment: That's a good point! I even campe up with this myself :) I have hidden the first up and the last down button and replaced it with blank space.